# LAN worlds not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I open my world to LAN, and when my friend tries to join it says "connection timed out no further information" so how do we play? I have Wi-Fi so I don't know... So how do I play on LAN if it says that all the time? I tried getting off Minecraft and my whole laptop so please help.

Comment: Most likely it's your firewall/antivirus software blocking the connection.  Not much you can do other than turn it off to check.  If it works, then all you can do if configure your firewall/AV to exclude minecraft.  If you don't know how to do it, i would google turn off avast (or whatever your antivirus is called).

Answer (score 1):

Check your Firewall/Antivirus software to see if that's blocking the connection. the most you can do for that is turn it on and off, if that doesn't work then unplug the LAN and plug it back in that's all I got for you